# String Array keep Returning 0/ null

Tags: c#

i have issue when using array and pass in to string = 0 .. its keep getting 0 although the excel sheet data got value. Kindly advice.

Below is the code sheetnameList = 0

```
string[] sheetnameList = GetExcelSheetName(@"" + 
    var_SourceFilePath + "MBF_Cancel_Temp.xlsx" + "");

foreach (string sheetName in sheetnameList)
{
    if (sheetName.Contains("$"))
    {
        InsertLogFile("AMB SP15 Cancellation: Processing SheetName " + sheetName);

        DeleteTable();

        DataTable sheetTable = loadSingleSheet(@"" + var_SourceFilePath + 
            "MBF_Cancel_Temp.xlsx" + "", sheetName);

        InsertDBMaster();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious... what's with concatenating empty strings at the beginning and end?  On topic; check your path.

Comment: I suggest you create the full file path in a separate line, and either check it in a debugger, or print it out so you can see what it is.

Comment: i was trying to push the data from excel into the array and pump data into SQL server.

Comment: when it goes to foreach statement , its encounter error with "Index was outside the bounds of the array." Kindly advice

Comment: yeah, sounds like an empty array then.  Either the `GetExcelSheetName` method isn't doing what you expect, or you're passing it a bad argument

Comment: but this code i been running quite well last month , but im not sure why suddenly not running and it catch error. Is there any solution where can apply on?

Comment: Perhaps formatting your code and removing commented sections would help.

Comment: I thought commented sections wouldn't affect the code?

Comment: It affects our reading of it

Comment: hmm .. i recheck back the path which indicate the excel file . its correct path location where to grab the excel sheet. but not sure what problem although i debug alot times-.- its getting me headache

Comment: If I run that code with sheetnameList = null, I get: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in <programname>; if I run it with sheetnameList=string[0], the program runs, but the body of the loop doesn't get run. In no case do I get "Index was outside the bounds of the array". It's clear the version of the program you posted doesn't match the error messages you're getting. As another commenter said, clean up and present one version of the code you want help with.

Comment: Run debugger with breakpoint on the first line (GetExcelSheetName); step over that line; examine the value of sheetnameList; post it here in a comment (or edit the original question). Failing that, put `Console.WriteLine(sheetnameList[0]);` (or `MessageBox.Show`) just after the first line and run it.

Comment: hmm .. i amend it and i re-run , it still the same getting null from the sheetnamelist.

Comment: /headslap ... somehow, I missed that "sheetnameList = 0" in your question meant that sheetnameList was showing `null` in a debug session. :( Anyway, see my answer to see if it helps; if not, put in my second version of the code (with `var path`), debug to that point, and see what value you get in the `path` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a hunch, try this:

```
string[] sheetnameList = GetExcelSheetName(var_SourceFilePath + @"\\" + "MBF_Cancel_Temp.xlsx");
```

or even better:

```
var path = Path.Combine(var_SourceFilePath, "MBF_Cancel_Temp.xlsx");
var sheetnameList = GetExcelSheetName(path);
```